# Determine $p,q\in\mathbb R$ such that $B^{-1}=(2A^4-12A^3+19A^2-29A+37I)^{-1}$ can be written as $pA+qI$ for square matrix $A$.

Tags: matrices

Determine $p,q\in\mathbb R$ such that $B^{-1}=(2A^4-12A^3+19A^2-29A+37I)^{-1}$ can be written as $pA+qI$ for $A=        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        2 & 5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$.

We can use Cayley–Hamilton theorem:

$$p_{A}(\lambda)=\lambda^2-6\lambda+7\Rightarrow A^2-6A+7I=0$$
$$2A^4-12A^3+19A^2-29A+37I=A^2(A^2-6A+7I)+A^4-6A^3+12A^2-29A+37I$$
$$=5A^2-29A+37I$$
$$=4A^2-23A+30I$$
$$=3A^2-17A+23I$$
$$=2A^2-11A+16I$$
$$=A^2-5A+9I$$
$$=A+2I$$

This means that $B=2A^4-12A^3+19A^2-29A+37I=A+2I\Rightarrow p=1,q=2$.

But, in the problem, it says to find $p,q$ such that $B^{-1}$ can be written as $pA+qI$, not $B$.

Does that mean that we need to solve the equation $pA+qI=(A+2I)^{-1}$?

This will give $p=-\frac{1}{23},q=\frac{8}{23}$.

Are both solutions correct?

Comment: Your solution seems correct.

Comment: @choco_addicted Which one?

Comment: Oh, I may find the minor error. Is it correct that $A^2-5A+9I$ can be converted to $-A-2I$? Should it be corrected as $A+2I$?

Comment: @choco_addicted You are correct. I will edit the post.

Comment: The solution for $B^{-1}$ is $(p,q)=\left(-\frac{1}{23},\frac{8}{23}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Cayley-Hamilton theorem,
$$
(A+2I)(A-8I)=-23I
$$
and so we can know that
$$
(A+2I)^{-1}=-\frac{1}{23}(A-8I).
$$